# Use of Scaler with LassoCV, RidgeCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to use scikit-learn LassoCV/RidgeCV while applying a 'StandardScaler' on each fold training set. I do not want to apply the scaler before the cross-validation to avoid leakage but I cannot figure out how I am supposed to do that with LassoCV/RidgeCV.

Is there a way to do this ? Or should I create a pipeline with Lasso/Ridge and 'manually' search for the hyperparameters (using GridSearchCV for instance) ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer through the scikit-learn mailing list so here it is:

'There is no way to use the "efficient" EstimatorCV objects with pipelines.
This is an API bug and there's an open issue and maybe even a PR for that.'

Many thanks to Andreas Mueller for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to apply the scaling to each iteration in cross-validation, you could use the make_pipeline function (this function will call "fit" on each training fold and call "transform" on each test fold)
- The make_my_pipe below can be considered as an esitmator with a StandardScaler attached to it.

code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X = "some data"
y = "the labels of the data"

make_my_pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), Ridge())
scores = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y)

print(scores)
```